# import/export save game data in js using lz-string

Tags: javascript, html, function, save

I have recently came across many many web-games, where you can import & export your save game data. where you would click "export" and once  its clicked, you would get a lot of random characters, I would like to be able to store my save game state in lz-string state but I don't know how to do it. If anyone knows absolute anything at all, please tell me, because any knowledge would be greatly appreciated.
`function saveGame() { var gameSave = { stars: Game.stars, totalStarsEarned: Game.totalStarsEarned, buildings:buildings, upgrades:upgrades, achievements:achievements, }; localStorage.setItem("gameSave", JSON.stringify(gameSave)); } function loadGame() { var savedGame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("gameSave")); if(localStorage.getItem("gameSave") !== null) { if(typeof savedGame.stars !== "undefined") Game.stars = savedGame.stars; if(typeof savedGame.totalStarsEarned !== "undefined") Game.totalStarsEarned = savedGame.totalStarsEarned; if(typeof savedGame.buildings !== "undefined") buildings =  savedGame.buildings; if(typeof savedGame.upgrades !== "undefined") upgrades =  savedGame.upgrades; if(typeof savedGame.achievements !== "undefined") achievements =  savedGame.achievements; }`
`eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoxLjMsImZlYXR1cmVzIjp7ImxvY2F0aW9uIjp7InJvb`

CODEDAMN
https://codedamn.com/playground/ml0olmk4dGuyWs6EBHAE4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use an external library for that, probably [lz-string](https://github.com/pieroxy/lz-string). Here's an example:

(BTW, please note difference from **base64** encoding)

```js
var game_data = {
  key: 'value'
}

var json = JSON.stringify(game_data)
var compressed = LZString.compress(json);
console.log(compressed)

// reverse:
var original_json = LZString.decompress(compressed)
var loaded_game_data = JSON.parse(original_json)
console.log(loaded_game_data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lz-string/1.4.4/lz-string.js" integrity="sha512-uKcuHr0POVc2zz1hMVTEiicF9G5SPq2k6l4xVmPeSXm8yH/rrM6ewau/Gn89ykaGrfMyhCBH4Vn/MDcS3Pccqw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Here's how to incorporate this into your code but it's basically the same.

```js
function saveGame() {
  var game_data = {
    stars: Game.stars,
    totalStarsEarned: Game.totalStarsEarned,
    buildings: buildings,
    upgrades: upgrades,
    achievements: achievements,
  }

  var json = JSON.stringify(game_data)
  var compressed = LZString.compress(json);
  localStorage.setItem("game_data", compressed)

}


function loadGame() {
  var str = localStorage.getItem("game_data");
  if (!str) {
    // load failed
    return;
  }

  var savedGame = JSON.parse(LZString.decompress(str));

  Game.stars = savedGame.stars;
  Game.totalStarsEarned = savedGame.totalStarsEarned;
  buildings = savedGame.buildings;
  upgrades = savedGame.upgrades;
  achievements = savedGame.achievements;

}
```

Comment: How would I go about implementing this into my own game, using the save/load game feature? Would I put the save vars into the "key: value" area?

Comment: of course. group all your variables into one object `{ }` called `gameData` or so.  you can  incorporate this into your code it before/after the JSON parse/stringify as in my example above.

Comment: Ok, so when I was testing to see if it worked, i added my code into it, and instead of "console.log' I added "alert" because Im in school and dont have access to console. But once I click my export button all I see is "㞂⃎ˠ蘄⸀〆萐㶴͠敩쀨각�怉ꊨ耑肮ɛ慣␎漂ͪ艔Ŭ쨡䨻䘁貣愆芙げ戰áᆆሢ̈撀老‪爀豉遢∋桯턧礚䢰쀀匣᜙ᬒ⨄㌴娨〲籏Ἷí悳_ᐾ䅡А!☖㙶⌀☫䕥唍ⴝ䳽䍓䋋䝛䑺웧圚༸壿䃠슰袨" and once I click enter 2 times, my export UI popups and still says undefined, am I able to share my codepen with you and I can show you? @IT goldman

Comment: yes. edit your answer to include the codepen link or even better a snippet of code

Comment: I edited my code sorry I took so long

Comment: can I send you a link to a site called codedamn? Because on codepen my code isnt working correctly

Comment: It doesn't say undefined it says [object Object] which means it worked. answer edited.

Comment: It works now but, when I added that code, when I click export, it says undefined in the box. @IT goldman

Comment: ^
|
|

EDIT
I figured out what I did wrong, thank you for your help